# Derive equations for the $S$-matrix composition in case of $2n$ by $2n$ full $S$-matrices

Tags: scattering, s-matrix-theory

I am studying computational physics, but for me it seems that this question should be asked in physics section. i need to derive equations for the $S$-matrix composition in case of $2n$ by $2n$ full $S$-matrices. I know how to do it in case of 2 by 2 matrices, because I write two S matrices of two slabs and write their composition in general form. Here when I have general size of a matrices it seem that multiplication in general form cant be simplified to some expression for $S_{ij}$. How can I solve this problem then?